# Checking if two lines are nearly parallel gives wrong results

Tags: c#, geometry, line

I'm using the following equation to find if two lines are parallel or not. But I'm having problems when the lines are nearly parallel and finally meet in the far distance.
I want an equation that considers these two nearly parallel lines as parallel.

```
var la = new Line {X1 = 1005, Y1 = 773, X2 = 1202, Y2 = 1198};
var lb = new Line {X1 = 1239, Y1 = 1181, X2 = 1550, Y2 = 1856};

var d = (lb.Y2 - lb.Y1) * (la.X2 - la.X1) - (lb.X2 - lb.X1) * (la.Y2 - la.Y1);
if (Math.Abs(d) < 0.001)
{
    // Return if lines are parallel
}
```

To my surprise the above equation for `d` results in a number far greater than 0.
What a I getting wrong here? Am I using the wrong equation?

I'm using this article:
http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/

Comment: What are the data types here - `int`, `double`, `decimal`, something else?

Comment: Don't multiply, divide! (And check for Div by 0)!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The data type is double.

Comment: I don't think your formula is correct... You should calculate the slopes of each line and compare them. Check out this article: http://www.wikihow.com/Figure-out-if-Two-Lines-Are-Parallel

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I picked this formula from some website and it has been working great so far in a CAD program. I just realized that it has problems with this kind of lines.

Comment: @TaW Can you please tell me to not multiply with part?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I found the article behind my formula. http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/

Comment: Both * should be / to get at the elevation/direction of the lines. You also confused the line points and  you need to do it in float like this: `var d = 1f * (lb.Y2 - lb.Y1) / (lb.X2 - lb.X1) - 1f *  (la.Y2 - la.Y1) / (la.X2 - la.X1);`

Comment: @TaW Thanks Taw, your answer solved the problem with the current line, I'm having the same problem with parallel lines parallel to horizontal axis.

Comment: Yup, those are special cases and have to be handled separatley; this comes free with the Div by 0 test!

Comment: @TaW You mean I should check if `(lb.X2 - lb.X1)` and (la.X2 - la.X1)` are Zero or not, and if the are zero the lines are parallel again? I did this didn't get any results.

Comment: If one is 0 its line it parallel to the x-axis, if both are they are prallel; if not use a large number as its result instead of the division to compare; the size will depend on the maximum coordinates of your points; maxint will be too large. Or go for calulating each line's direction in degrees!

Comment: @Taw The answer Nico gave worked just fine, but I was expecting a rather light answer that doesn't require `sqrt`.

Comment: Actually sqrt is very cheap, so don't worry!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Slopes are hard to compare. Two lines with the slopes 7 and 8 are closer to each other than two lines with the slopes 1 and 2, although the slope difference is always the same.

Instead, we should compare the resulting angle which can be calculated with the dot product:

```
dx1 = la.X2 - la.X1
dy1 = la.Y2 - la.Y1
dx2 = lb.X2 - lb.X1
dy2 = lb.Y2 - lb.Y1
cosAngle = abs((dx1 * dx2 + dy1 * dy2) / sqrt((dx1 * dx1 + dy1 * dy1) * (dx2 * dx2 + dy2 * dy2)))
```

If the lines are perfect parallel (or anti-parallel), `cosAngle` will be 1. It will decrease by the cosine of the angle in between both lines. So if there is an angle of 10° between the lines, `cosAngle` will be 0.9848. You can specify an arbitrary threshold above which lines are considered parallel. Then

```
if(cosAngle > threshold) //threshold = cos(threshold angle)
    // parallel or anti-parallel
else
    // not parallel
```

If you want to distinguish anti-parallelness, leave the `abs` away. Then negative values stand for anti-parallelity.

Comment: Thanks Nico, What is anti-parallel? you mean nearly parallel?

Comment: Anti-parallel means that one vector points in one direction and the other in the opposite direction. It's usually not relevant for lines (because they have no forward and backward), so anti-parallelity can be assumed to be parallel