# Cluster the lines which are stand alone

Tags: c#, image, math, image-processing, geometry

I have a list of lines [image: lines]
as you can see in the image. Now I want to cluster the lines which are not parallel or close to the next lines [image: the single line that I want to cluster]

and add them to another list. I am using C#, and the information for each line I have is the endpoints' coordinate which is described here [image: the endpoint of 1 line]. What should I do for clustering them and add them to another list?

Comment: You need the slope of the lines m = (y2 -y1)/(x2 - x1).  The slopes may not be exactly the same so you may want to test a range of values so if you have m1 and m2 you want to use absolute(m1 - m2) < 0.1 (or whatever range you want).

Comment: Thank you for your response
Following to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989355/checking-if-two-lines-are-nearly-parallel-gives-wrong-results
I used slopes for measuring if they are parallel or not, but it is not good as using angles.

Comment: Slopes and angles are the same!!!  The angle = ArcTan(slope).